# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.chart.JFreeChartInfo.setLibraries(Ljava/util/List;)V Exception

Tags: java, charts, bar-chart, jfreechart, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to draw a barchart using JFreeChart and I insert data to dataset from a MySQL database. When I compile it gives me a exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.chart.JFreeChartInfo.setLibraries(Ljava/util/List;)V
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: which jfreechart version you use?

Comment: jfreechart-1.0.4 @FastSnail

Comment: Maybe this helps http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26652

Comment: Some places to look for extraneous jars are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20java.ext.dirs).